# Templates are set to initial states on switch in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using template tags in my code for dynamic rendering and it's working great but when i am implementing the checkboxes in the template they are set to initial state on switching to other templates and on return to the template where checkboxes are implemented. As per the code initially they are unchecked and when i checked them and switched to yourteam section the objects appear in that section but when i goes back to batsman they are unchecked even though i didn't unchecked them.

### team.component.html

```
<ul class="fields-heading">
    <li class="fields"> <a (click)="selectMode='yourteam'"      [class.active]="selectMode=='yourteam'">YourTeam</a></li>
    <li class="fields"> <a (click)="selectMode='batsman'" [class.active]="selectMode=='batsman'"> Batsman</a></li>    

</ul> 

<div [ngSwitch]="selectMode">
<template [ngSwitchWhen]="'yourteam'"> Your Team
<li *ngFor="#value of checked">{{value}}</li>

 </template>
 <template [ngSwitchWhen]="'batsman'" >         
     <div  *ngFor="#player of players; #i=index" >
    <div *ngIf="player.type=='batsman'">
         <form class="controls-stacked">
                <label class="control checkbox">  
                <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateChecked(player,$event)">
                <span class="control-indicator"></span>
                {{ player.name }}
                </label>            
            </form>        
     </div>
 </div>         
  </template>
```

### team.component.ts

```
 export class TeamComponent  {
    selectMode = 'batsman';
    checked: string[] = [];
    players=[{
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "player1",
    "type": "batsman",
    "team" : "team1"
     },{ 
     "id": 2,
     "name" : "player2",
     "type": "batsman",
     "team" : "team1"

     }];

    updateChecked(player,event){ 

    var index = this.checked.indexOf(player);
    if(event.target.checked){
        if(index===-1){
            this.checked.push(player);
        }
    }else{
        if(index!==-1){
            this.checked.splice(index,1);
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox value is not bind to any variable. I will suggest the following:

**team.component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="player.checked"(ngModelChange)="updateChecked(player,$event)">
```

Use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`. Angular 2 does not detect `(change)` reliably. Ref:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10038#issuecomment-232366532

**team.component.ts**

```
 export class TeamComponent  {
    selectMode = 'batsman';
    checked: string[] = [];
    players=[{
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "player1",
    "type": "batsman",
    "team" : "team1",
    "checked" : false
     },{ 
     "id": 2,
     "name" : "player2",
     "type": "batsman",
     "team" : "team1"
     "checked" : false
     }];

    updateChecked(player,event){ 

    var index = this.checked.indexOf(player);
    if(event.target.checked){
        if(index===-1){
            this.checked.push(player);
        }
    }else{
        if(index!==-1){
            this.checked.splice(index,1);
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hey this code helped in retaining the state of the checkbox but with this the binding value didn't showed up in the yourteam section which perviously worked. After going through the github link i resolved this issue with this line of code. And thanks for your quick help. It really handy.                                                                                                <input type="checkbox" (ngModel)]="player.checked" (change)="updateChecked(player,$event)">

Comment: @kurrisudarshanreddy strange you have to use (change) to make it work. I personally ran into checkbox + (change) issue before and have to use (ngModelChange).